# Is there a way to remove rattling in MacBook Air 2020 speakers?

Tags: macbook-pro, music, speakers, spotify

My Mac is Macbook Air M1 2020. Now I use Mac OS Monterey 12.0.1. Sometimes I experience rattling in the speakers.
Specifically, rattling is easy to hear while listening to "Paris by $uicideboy$" on Spotify and other tracks with similar sounds.
Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Rattling or buzzing on low-frequency audio is usually a good sign you've blown the cones. If you use a custom EQ curve or any plugin to enhance 'loudness', more so.

Comment: @Tetsujin So you mean that I am hitting the borders of the capabilities of my speakers?

Comment: I surmise you have hit the limits of capability hard enough & for long enough to have caused permanent damage.